# Formatting SQL code

Tags: listings, lstlisting, lstdefinestyle

I try to format SQL code to achieve at least similar result to this picture :

[image: Desirable result from MS Word]

My result:
[image]

But I can not do that. I struggle with margins, paddings, and numbering for a long time and I already feel desperate so asking for help. It seems to me that framesep and framextopmargin don't work at all. I am sorry if my code is confusing or too complicated I don't have any experience with packages like that yet.

[You can open it on Overleaf also](https://www.overleaf.com/read/wwnqdctnjjwn)

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
 \usepackage[paperwidth=841pt,paperheight=595pt,top=28pt,right=28pt,bottom=28pt,left=28pt, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
    \usepackage{xcolor,listings}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{color}

    \definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
    \definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
    \definecolor{codepurple}{HTML}{C42043}
    \definecolor{backcolour}{HTML}{F2F2F2}
    \definecolor{bookColor}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.90}  
    \color{bookColor}

    \lstset{upquote=true}

    \lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
        backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
        commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
        keywordstyle=\color{codepurple},
        numberstyle=\footnotesize\color{codegray},
        stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
        basicstyle=\footnotesize,
        breakatwhitespace=false,         
        breaklines=true,                 
        captionpos=b,                    
        keepspaces=true,                 
        numbers=left,                    
        numbersep=-10pt,                  
        showspaces=false,                
        showstringspaces=false,
        showtabs=false,      
    }
    \lstset{style=mystyle} 

    \begin{document}

        \begin{lstlisting}[language=SQL,
        deletekeywords={IDENTITY,INT},
        morekeywords={clustered},    
        framesep=10pt,
        framextopmargin=10pt]

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CisDuvodNezajmu] (
        [OID] [ INT ] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL INT,
        [Nazev] [NVARCHAR](100) COLLATE Czech_CI_AS NULL,
        [Cre] [DATETIME] NULL,
        [CreBy] [INT] NULL,
        [Mod] [DATETIME] NULL,
        [ModBy] [INT] NULL,
        [OptimisticLockField] [INT] NULL,
        [GCRecord] [INT] NULL,
         CONSTRAINT[PK_CisDuvodNezajmu] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OID])
        );
    \end{lstlisting}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are some notes on how to get closer to the desired result.

**Indentation:** First of all, do not indent all code of your document. You might run in trouble if you indent everything and thus get code listings which are indented too much, because all the indentation spaces are kept by `listings` (unless you use the `gobble` option to remove the first *n* characters from every listing line). As no other automatic code indentation is provided, you have to indent the code according to the output you expect.

**Font type:** The usual font type for code listings is a monospace font. So you might want to add `\ttfamily` to the `basicstyle` option. Have a look at the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html) if you can find a font that is closer to the one in your example image.

**Line numbers:** As the style for the line numbers is a bit more extensive, we can move that into a new command `\numberstyle`, where the current line number is the first parameter. The line numbers in your example are also set in `\ttfamily` font. Also there's a leading zero and trailing pipe, which can be easily accomplished by unsing `\ifnum#1<10 0\fi#1 |` (at least if the numbers stay below 100).

**Margins:** As the line numbers now are too wide to the left, we have to adjust the listing's margins. First, we move the whole listing a bit to the right by setting `xleftmargin`. Next, we extend the background to the left with `framexleftmargin`. Finally, `numbersep` gives fine control on where the line numbers should be positioned.

The missing additional margins on the top and bottom can be achieved by setting `framesep` and/or `framex(top|bottom)margin`. As `listings` only seems to render those if an actual frame is specified, we can add an invisible top/bottom frame with `frame=tb, framerule=0pt`.

**Keywords:** The `SQL` language style has defined two sets of keywords, 1 for language keywords and  2 for type names (this is documented in the [drivers file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.pdf)). When you say `deletekeywords={IDENTITY,INT}` that means the keywords should be deleted from the default keyword set, i.e. set 1. But this set doesn't include the `INT` keyword, that's in set 2. So to still remove it, you have to use another option with the proper set number added to the argument: `deletekeywords={[2]INT},`. This syntax is also used for the other `*keywords*` options.

With everything put together it looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=841pt,paperheight=595pt,top=28pt,right=28pt,bottom=28pt,left=28pt, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{HTML}{C42043}
\definecolor{backcolour}{HTML}{F2F2F2}
\definecolor{bookColor}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.90}  
\color{bookColor}

\lstset{upquote=true}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{codepurple},
    numberstyle=\numberstyle,
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=10pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\newcommand\numberstyle[1]{%
    \footnotesize
    \color{codegray}%
    \ttfamily
    \ifnum#1<10 0\fi#1 |%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[ language=SQL,
                    deletekeywords={IDENTITY},
                    deletekeywords={[2]INT},
                    morekeywords={clustered},
                    framesep=8pt,
                    xleftmargin=40pt,
                    framexleftmargin=40pt,
                    frame=tb,
                    framerule=0pt ]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CisDuvodNezajmu] (
      [OID] [ INT ] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL INT,
      [Nazev] [NVARCHAR](100) COLLATE Czech_CI_AS NULL,
      [Cre] [DATETIME] NULL,
      [CreBy] [INT] NULL,
      [Mod] [DATETIME] NULL,
      [ModBy] [INT] NULL,
      [OptimisticLockField] [INT] NULL,
      [GCRecord] [INT] NULL,
  CONSTRAINT[PK_CisDuvodNezajmu] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OID])
);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just concerning indentation: The autogobble feature is quite usable…

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks, I didn't know about that feature. I added a note to the answer

Comment: Thank you very much @siracusa, your solution is perfect. The only thing I can't get is why INT is still purple highlighted despite that we used deletekeywords={IDENTITY,INT}.

Comment: @Josef Good point, I missed that. Please see the updated answer.